# Spring create One bean before all others

Tags: java, spring

Returning to Spring after a long time and trying to add it to an existing application.

App start point (assume there is an `Environment` object here, which provides configuration elements from a file):

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
  try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class)) {
    EnvironmentConfig environmentConfig = context.getBean(EnvironmentConfig.class);
    environmentConfig.setEnvironment(environment);

    // TODO move to being a bean with EnvironmentConfig being a dependency
    final BeanA beanA = new BeanA(environmentConfig.getStorage());

    // TODO move to being a bean with BeanA being a dependency
    final BeanB beanB = new BeanB(BeanA);
  }
}
```

I have a AppConfig setup for component scan like:

```
package com.company.packageX;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.packageX")
public class AppConfig {}
```

So I need to create two beans (as above) but also want them to be auto-wired with dependencies.

Problem is that I am setting up `environment` in `EnvironmentConfig` only in the `main method`. If I move the creation of Beans by annotating the two with `@Component`, not sure that they will get the EnvironmentConfig with environment being already set, as Beans are created when `ComponentScan` runs.

Comment: You're trying to do everything manually that spring will do for you automatically.  Is there a reason for not just adding @Component to BeanA and BeanB and adding the appropriate dependencies to the constructor?

Comment: Thanks lane.maxwell. I do want to use @Component for BeanA and BeanB, as mentioned in the original question. Just not sure whether they will get the EnvrionmentConfig with the original setup as I am doing it manually here. That is the main issue, how to pass this state and make other bean instantiate after EnvironmentConfig Bean has been updated.

Comment: What is the "original question"? Can you create a `@Configuration` and return your classes from a `@Bean` method?

Comment: If one of the beans needs setup before other beans use it, the init method of the beans can be used to ensure order.  This can be accomplished by putting an init method on the `EnvironmentConfig` bean that makes it ready for use, and then init methods on it's consuming beans that then make use of it.  Spring makes sure the order of init method calls is based on bean dependencies.

Comment: BTW, looking at the name `EnvironmentConfig` it sounds like functionality that Spring already provides.  You can have environment-specific config files, and in your beans just ignore the environment part (e.g. `$Value("configA")`).  Spring switches between the different environment-specific configuration files itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Environment` is a Bean, you can configure it like this.

```
@Component
public class EnvironmentConfig {
  private final Environment environment;

  public EnvironmentConfig (Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  // declare this method to return whatever type storage is, assuming it's an object of type Storage
  public Storage getStorage() {
    return storage from wherever it comes from
  }
}
```

If `Environment` is not a Bean, then there are several options for creating it.  You could just construct it in the constructor.

```
@Component
public class EnvironmentConfig {
  private final Environment environment;

  public EnvironmentConfig() {
    this.environment = new Environment();
  }
}
```

Or, you could implement `InitializingBean` and create it there.

```
@Component
public class EnvironmentConfig implements InitializingBean {
  private Environment environment;

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    this.environment = new Environment();
  }
}
```

Or, you can a `@PostConstruct` method and build it there.

```
@Component
public class EnvironmentConfig {
  private Environment environment;

  @PostConstruct
  public void initializeMyCollaboratorsThatAreNotBeans() {
    this.environment = new Environment();
  }
}
```

The point here is that there are many ways to create a bean of your `EnvironmentConfig`, then you can inject it into your other beans as you normally would.  This definition of A and B would satisfy what you've laid out here, I believe.

```
@Component
public class BeanA {
  private final Storage storage;

  public BeanA (EnvironmentConfig environmentConfig) {
    this.storage = environmentConfig.getStorage();
  }
}

@Component
public class BeanB {
  private final BeanA beanA;

  public BeanB (BeanA beanA) {
    this.beanA = beanA;
  }
}
```